# Why am I unable to display a d3 plot?

Tags: html, d3.js

I am unable to display a D3 plot on a web-page.

I am able to display the plot when I select `<body>`. However, I cannot display a plot when I select a, say, `<div>`.

The following is my setting:

[image]

**plot.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
      <title>Protein Structure Analyzer</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/jquery/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/d3/d3.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 30},
        width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    var svG = d3.select("#plot-div")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    // Create data
    var data = [ {x:10, y:20}, {x:40, y:90}, {x:80, y:50} ]
    
    // X scale and Axis
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100])         // This is the min and the max of the data: 0 to 100 if percentages
        .range([0, width]);       // This is the corresponding value I want in Pixel
    svG
      .append('g')
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    
    // X scale and Axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100])         // This is the min and the max of the data: 0 to 100 if percentages
        .range([height, 0]);       // This is the corresponding value I want in Pixel
    svG
      .append('g')
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    
    // Add 3 dots for 0, 50 and 100%
    svG
      .selectAll("whatever")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d){ return x(d.x) })
        .attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d.y) })
        .attr("r", 7)
    </script>
    <div id="plot-div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**What am I doing incorrectly?**

Comment: The DIV needs to be in the document *before* the script runs so just move the DIV to the top of the document.

Comment: @MarkMcClure, Doesn't work.

Comment: @user366312 Sure seems to work to me. The only differences between your code and the code I've got in my answer is the version of D3 that's being used, the fact that I'm only loading D3 once, and the fact that the script is loaded first, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DIV needs to be in the document before the script runs so just move the DIV to the top of the document:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svG = d3.select("#plot-div")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Create data
var data = [ {x:10, y:20}, {x:40, y:90}, {x:80, y:50} ]

// X scale and Axis
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])         // This is the min and the max of the data: 0 to 100 if percentages
    .range([0, width]);       // This is the corresponding value I want in Pixel
svG
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// X scale and Axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])         // This is the min and the max of the data: 0 to 100 if percentages
    .range([height, 0]);       // This is the corresponding value I want in Pixel
svG
  .append('g')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Add 3 dots for 0, 50 and 100%
svG
  .selectAll("whatever")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return x(d.x) })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d.y) })
    .attr("r", 7)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot-div"></div>
```